# Nodejs - how create crypto key and save it in a file to use later?

Tags: node.js, encryption

Create key => save it => use it to encrypt passwords from registrations in a website

Is this secure to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to ask, the answer is generally "no." You should be using a tested, audited, and proven crypto library to do your password transformations, and *never store passwords themselves, encrypted or otherwise*. You need to hash them using a cryptographically secure, one-way hash function with a salt and enough resource consumption to deter hash cracking attempts down the road.

If you don't know what any of that means, that's fine, but it means you shouldn't be trying to do these things yourself; let a tool (e.g. a popular library or framework) do it for you. Without knowing what web site technologies you're working with, I can't give you a very good recommendation about specific methods.